# Multidimensional array to string with each sub-array on new line

Tags: arrays, string

I'm trying to convert a multidimensional array like this:

```
var array = [["ID","Cue","Target","InitialCopyLen","InitialCopyStrict","NumStudied","NumTested","NumDropped","studyCountLen","testCountLen","studyCountStrict","testCountStrict","finaltestLen","finaltestStrict"],["bl","AGLUK","JAW","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],["bl","AKI","MONEY","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]];
```

to something like this (as a string):

```
ID  Cue Target  InitialCopyLen  InitialCopyStrict   NumStudied  NumTested   NumDropped  studyCountLen   testCountLen    studyCountStrict    testCountStrict finaltestLen    finaltestStrict
bl  AGLUK   JAW 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
bl  AKI MONEY   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I tried converting to a string first, then using a replace function:

```
var newString = array.toString(array);
newString = newString.replace(/.{14}/g, '$&\n');
```

But obviously this just does every 14th character, and I need every 14th comma.

I then thought about something like this:

```
var i;
var commaCount = 0;
for (i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
    if (i == ","){
        commaCount++
       if (commaCount == "14"){
          // INSERT NEW LINE HERE    
       }
    }
} 

x.innerHTML = newString;
```

But perhaps there is a smarter way to do this? I basically want to convert the entire big array into a string, with each sub-array on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

Inspite of iterating through every element in the inner array ,You can use `for-each` loop to separately convert each part of array to String.

```
for(var element : array){
     str = element.toString();
     System.out.println(str);
     }
```

System.out.println() will take care of "\n"

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble following the code. Could you show me in a JSfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/xxPoLyGLoTxx/re4n216k/86/

Also it must be a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Actually I know java and don't know much of javasciript.

Comment: Happy that you found a solution :) .Mark it correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
array.forEach(function(element) {
        x.innerHTML += element + "<br>";
    });`
```